# How to make loading scene before it connects to the MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I am trying to make a loading window. But I have problem with MySQL driver. It's problem, when I add some object, in my case GIF(but I tried also rectangle), to my scene (to Group) and then it connects to database, stage doesn't display any object until the database connection is complete.

I tried some of examples what I found on the Internet, but nothing works. So I find help here. Here's the code I tried.

```
private void afterClick() {
    showLoading();
    username = name.getText();
    password = passField.getText();
    if ((username.length() == 0) && (password.length() == 0)) {
        Alert.printInformation("Nezadali jste přihlašovací údaje.");
    } else if (username.length() == 0) {
        Alert.printInformation("Nezadali jste login.");
    } else if (password.length() == 0) {
        Alert.printInformation("Nezadali jste heslo.");
    } else {
        DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
        if(connection.connect()){
            if (check.isSelected()) {
                FileStream.writeToFile("Account.txt", LoginMenu.username + ";" + LoginMenu.password, false);
            } else {
                FileStream.writeToFile("Account.txt", "empty", false);
            }
            App.showScene(MenuName.MainMenu);
        }
    }

}



void showLoading(){

    ImageView loading = new ImageView(new Image("file:Wallpapers/loading.gif"));
    loading.setX(App.width -100);
    loading.setY(App.height - 100);
    loading.setFitWidth(60);
    loading.setFitHeight(60);

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Group group = new Group();
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(group);
    group.getChildren().add(loading);
    stage.setScene(scene1);
    scene1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: You must never block, nor run long running tasks on, the _JavaFX Application Thread_. When you do it stops the thread from doing anything else which results in a frozen GUI. You should move the heavy work to another thread—but remember you _must_ never modify the GUI from the background thread. See [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) for more information.

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple! You can make some "pre" moves with overriding initialize method.

```
class YourControllerClass implements Initializable{
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Also you can run in initialize method new Thread like this to prevent blocking your app.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    //Your stuff
}).run();
```